# Serialize list objects to JSON using C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I need some suggestions on how to import data into multiple list objects using Dapper and then serialize the lists into proper JSON format. Please share your suggestions. THANKS!

**1. Sample JSON format**

```
{
  "students": [
    {
      "studentId": "",
      "emailAddresses": [
        {
          "emailAddress": ""
        }
      ],      
      "lastName": "",
      "directory": {
        "addresses": [
          {
            "city": "",
            "state": ""
          }
        ],      
      }     
    }
  ]
}
```

**2. Classes**

```
public class Student
{
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }  
    public List<EmailAddresses> emailAddresses { get; set; }
}

public class EmailAddresses
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }    
}
```

**3. Data coming in from sql query**

```
StudentId   Gender  EmailAddress
123456  Female  maryjoe@gmail.com
123456  Female  mary.joe@mycollege.edu
123456  Female  mj@hotmail.com
```

**4. Dapper code I am trying to implement**

```
 public List<Student> GetStudentData()
 {
     List<Student> dataStudent;
     using (IDbConnection connection = RepositoryHelper.OpenConnection())
     {
         dataStudent = connection.Query<Student, EmailAddresses, Student>("mystoredprocedure",
            (c, cc) =>
            {
                c.EmailAddresses = cc;
                return c;
            }, splitOn: "EmailAddress").ToList();

        }

    return dataStudent;
}
```

**4. Serializing to JSON**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    List<Student> students = GetStudentData();
    var json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
                                                  .Serialize(students);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so what's the actual problem? Is the code you have shown not working? At what point is it failing? How is it failing?

Comment: Dapper code is failing. The connection query is complaining about the EmailAddresses object.  dataStudent = connection.Query<Student, EmailAddresses, Student....... Namespace "EmailAddresses" could not be found.

Comment: Complaining how? What error message is it giving you? Is it giving you an error at compile time? Or run time? You might want to focus your question just on that part and then if you have a problem further down the road (for example with the serialization), ask a separate question about that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that you are invoking a stored procedure without specifying that the command type is a stored procedure.  This will mis-translate your proc name into a sql command which will obviously fail.

However, based on your updated comment, the second problem is that you are mis-using dapper's multi mapper functionality. This functionality is for mapping multiple tables to multiple objects.  However, it seems like your stored procedure is giving you a flattened object and you need to break apart unique records based on student id, mapping the email addresses to your email address property.

Dynamic works really well for this since we can map the data on the fly.

```
public List<Student> GetStudentData()
{
    List<Student> dataStudent;
    using (IDbConnection connection = RepositoryHelper.OpenConnection())
    {
        dataStudent = connection.Query<dynamic>(
            "mystoredprocedure", 
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)
                .GroupBy(x => x.StudentId)
                .Select(x => new Student 
                    { 
                        StudentId = x.First().StudentId, 
                        Gender = x.First().Gender,
                        emailAddresses = x.Select(ea => new EmailAddresses 
                            { 
                                EmailAddress = ea.emailAddresses 
                            }).ToList()
                    }).ToList();

        return dataStudent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is perfect. Just what I needed and the data is being converted to JSON without any problems. Awesome. Thank you so much, I hope you have a wonderful day, you deserve it. :)

Comment: Hello David L. Do you think you could help me with this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31052520/linq-group-each-class You were so helpful on this one

Comment: @1111lt I added an answer for you.  Hopefully it helps :).