# Linq - group each class

Tags: c#, linq

I need help removing duplicates form the emailaddresses list. I need to add the code to group emailaddresses within the emailaddresses class. Sql is returning duplicate email addresses because of the different telephone numbers. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Here is my code:
**1. Classes**

```
public class Student
{
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }  
    public List<EmailAddresses> emailAddresses { get; set; }
}

public class EmailAddresses
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }    
}
```

**2. Data coming from sql query**

```
StudentId   EmailAddresses  IsPreferred Number  TelephoneType                                                                                               
123456789   maryjoe@gmail.com   FALSE   5556565 Present Evening Phone                                                                                               
123456789   maryjoe@gmail.com   FALSE   8885566 Permanent Day Phone                                                                                             
123456789   mary.joe@cuu.edu    TRUE    5556565 Present Evening Phone                                                                                               
123456789   mary.joe@cuu.edu    TRUE    8885566 Permanent Day Phone                                                                                             
456789123   dh@mycollege.edu    TRUE    7513150 Business Day Phone                                                                                              
456789123   donna.hill@cu.edu   TRUE    4123300 Present Day Phone                                                                                               
456789123   donna.hill@cu.edu   FALSE   4123300 Present Day Phone
```

**3. Code**

```
public List<Student> GetStudentData()
{
    List<Student> dataStudent;
    using (IDbConnection connection = RepositoryHelper.OpenConnection())
    {
        dataStudent = connection.Query<dynamic>(
            "mystoredprocedure", 
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)
                .GroupBy(x => x.StudentId)
                .Select(x => new Student 
                    { 
                        StudentId = x.First().StudentId, 
                        Gender = x.First().Gender,
                        emailAddresses = x.Select(ea => new EmailAddresses 
                            { 
                                EmailAddress = ea.emailAddresses 
                            }).ToList()
                    }).ToList();

        return dataStudent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't label pieces of code/data as Javascript code snippets when they're not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it would be preferable to filter out duplicates before returning, it also increases the complexity of your code.  If your result set is small, the memory and cpu overhead of filtering after you've returned the data may be suffer-able to easily and clearly get the results that you need.  You can use a custom `IEqualityComparer` to check for distinct results and create a new emailAddresses list on each Student record that contains distinct email addresses.

```
public List<Student> GetStudentData()
{
    List<Student> dataStudent;
    using (IDbConnection connection = RepositoryHelper.OpenConnection())
    {
        dataStudent = connection.Query<dynamic>(
            "mystoredprocedure", 
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)
                .GroupBy(x => x.StudentId)
                .Select(x => new Student 
                    { 
                        StudentId = x.First().StudentId, 
                        Gender = x.First().Gender,
                        emailAddresses = x.Select(ea => new EmailAddresses 
                            { 
                                EmailAddress = ea.emailAddresses 
                            }).ToList()
                    }).ToList();

        dataStudent.ForEach(x => x.emailAddresses = x.emailAddresses
            .Distinct(new StudentEmailEqualityComparer()).ToList());

        return dataStudent;
    }
}

public class StudentEmailEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<EmailAddresses>
{

    public bool Equals(EmailAddresses x, EmailAddresses y)
    {
        return x.EmailAddress.Equals(y.EmailAddress);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(EmailAddresses obj)
    {
        return obj.EmailAddress.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Almost there :). My EmailAddresses class has one one property called "IsPreferred". I am having trouble updating the foreach line to add the new prperty. Any suggestions. I can't get the syntax right. I have added the "IsPreferred property to the StudentEmailEqualityComparer class and that part seems to be fine. Thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: Does IsPreferred exist on your database payload?  If it does, you should be assigning it in emailAddresses = x.Select(ea => new EmailAddresses 
                            { 
                                EmailAddress = ea.emailAddresses 
                            }).ToList(), not the foreach

Comment: It works, thank you so much. I was a mistake on my end. I appreciate your help. Have a good day!!

Answer (score 1):

If i get you correct you need to get distinct values for that you can do like this

```
 List<Product> list = products
                   .GroupBy(a => a.Code )
                   .Select(g => g.First())
                   .ToList();
```

or

Create comperare and than try to find out distinct object

article for full code : [DistinctBy in Linq (Find Distinct object by Property)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/535374/DistinctBy-in-Linq-Find-Distinct-object-by-Propert)

```
    class ProductComparare : IEqualityComparer<product>
    {
        private Func<Product, object> _funcDistinct;
        public ProductComparare(Func<Product, object> funcDistinct)
        {
            this._funcDistinct = funcDistinct;
        }

        public bool Equals(Product x, Product y)
        {
            return _funcDistinct(x).Equals(_funcDistinct(y));
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Product obj)
        {
            return this._funcDistinct(obj).GetHashCode();
        }
    }

var list2 = products.Distinct(new ProductComparare( a => a.Code ));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am a bit lost could you please help me apply this code to my example above. The student object is later converted to JSON and I was wondering how I can get rid of the duplicates in the emailaddresses class before the data is converted. Thanks,

Comment: Any suggestions please? I am bit desperate. Thanks.

Comment: @1111lt - replace product by student class and you can try out...check the link in answer that shows example of it...if you want distict by two property than you can do this two time var list2 = students.Distinct(new StudentComparare( a => a.id  )); than var list2 =  list2.Distinct(new StudentComparare( a => a.emailid )); may resolve your issue